# How to manipulate neural network output data?

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, neural-networks

I have a large list data for neural network training in the form

```
{x1 -> y1, … , xn -> yn}
```

Where the outputs $y_i$ is either 1 or 0 and the inputs $x_i$ are real numbers.

After building the neural network I realise my data is in wrong form for classification problem. The input parts are fine but if $Y=1$ it should instead be $\{1,0\}$ and if $Y=0$ it should instead be $\{0,1\}$ so that either we have

```
xi -> {1,0}
```

or

```
xi -> {0,1}
```

for each sample.

Is there a way this can be fixed?

Comment: Without any more details about the format of your data, something like: `Map[#[[1]] -> If[#[[2]] == 0, {0, 1}, {1, 0}] &, input]` might work. But you will need to add more details about your input data to get a more helpful answer :)

Comment: @CarlLange I’ve edited it if that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: In place of ‘input’ should I put the name of the data list?

Comment: Yes, give that a go. From your extra details it looks like it should be OK.